# How can I get Keys of Object of an Key in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create some script which will take a Object and then return a list of all keys in that Object which works for two level keys. But once the key has another object or the Key is an Array holding Objects the script no longer returns the keys. Is there a simple way to do this or will I have to manually loop thru all keys and check if there is another object? Below is a sample object. In my case I don't care about the values but I need all keys:

```
object1 = {
            DocId: "email_campaign::3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102",
            _id: "3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102",
            _type :"email_campaign",
            end_date: "",
            history: {
                created_by: "",
                created_on: "",
                update_on: "",
                updated_by: ""
            },
            librarys :[{id: 1, name : 'Lib 1'},{ id: 2, name: 'Lib 2'}],
            metrics : {
                first_email_sent: "",
                last_email_send: "",
                nbr_of_attachments_opened: 0,
                nbr_of_bounces: 0,
                nbr_of_email_opened: 0,
                nbr_of_emails: 0,
                nbr_of_unique_attachments_opened:0,
                nbr_of_unique_email_opened: 0
            },
            start_date: "",
            status: "Active",
            subject: "Test 1 Subject",
            summary: "",
            tags: ['one', 'two'],
            template_id: ""
        };
```

Comment: Can you clarify this? "which works for to level keys"

Comment: You may want to post what code you have for getting keys currently, but my guess is that you'll want to turn it into a recursive function that can call itself whenever it finds another level deep.

Comment: so if i use lodash / underscore and this simple code let myKeys = _.allKeys(obj) i get for example metrics but not the keys under metrics

Comment: In your example, I see nowhere that "the key has another object or the Key is an Array holding Objects". I see places where the *value* is an object, and where the *value* is an array of objects, but that's different.

Comment: maybe i interchanged terms but for example metrics is a key in the object and has a bunch of nested keys or the librarys key has an array of another object which has 2 keys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062922/how-to-get-all-keys-with-values-from-nested-objects answers some part as it handles keys like history and metrics but not the librarys array

Comment: Use answers from [Javascript - Traverse through the Json Object and get each item hierarchical key including nested objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59134046/215552)

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help you. This gives you an array of key value. You can tweak it as per your use case.

```js
const object1 = {
  DocId: "email_campaign::3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102",
  _id: "3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102",
  _type :"email_campaign",
  end_date: "",
  history: {
      created_by: "",
      created_on: "",
      update_on: "",
      updated_by: ""
  },
  librarys : [{id: 1, name : 'Lib 1', id: 2, name: 'Lib 2'}],
  metrics : {
      first_email_sent: "",
      last_email_send: "",
      nbr_of_attachments_opened: 0,
      nbr_of_bounces: 0,
      nbr_of_email_opened: 0,
      nbr_of_emails: 0,
      nbr_of_unique_attachments_opened:0,
      nbr_of_unique_email_opened: 0
  },
  start_date: "",
  status: "Active",
  subject: "Test 1 Subject",
  summary: "",
  tags: ['one', 'two'],
  template_id: ""
};

function getKeyValues(obj, path = [], result = []) {
  let value;
  let fieldPath;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    value = obj[key];
    const modifiedKey = isNaN(key) ? key : `[${key}]`;
    fieldPath = path.concat([modifiedKey]);
    if (value instanceof Object) {
      getKeyValues(value, fieldPath, result);
    }
    result.push({"key": fieldPath.join("."), value});
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getKeyValues(object1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` ?

```js
const object1 = {
  DocId: "email_campaign::3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102",
  _id: "3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102",
  _type :"email_campaign",
  end_date: "",
  history: {
      created_by: "",
      created_on: "",
      update_on: "",
      updated_by: ""
  },
  librarys : [{id: 1, name : 'Lib 1', id: 2, name: 'Lib 2'}],
  metrics : {
      first_email_sent: "",
      last_email_send: "",
      nbr_of_attachments_opened: 0,
      nbr_of_bounces: 0,
      nbr_of_email_opened: 0,
      nbr_of_emails: 0,
      nbr_of_unique_attachments_opened:0,
      nbr_of_unique_email_opened: 0
  },
  start_date: "",
  status: "Active",
  subject: "Test 1 Subject",
  summary: "",
  tags: ['one', 'two'],
  template_id: ""
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
```

Comment: It would not get keys from nested objects

Comment: "But once the key has another object or the Key is an Array holding Objects the script no longer returns the keys." sounds like you are NOT wanting nested objects

Comment: I need both, the netsed objects as well as objects in array